# How to prove the signal separability property of 2D DFT? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 2d, fft, dft

I tried to prove the separability of a signal property of 2D Fourier transform using a 2D matrix that's separable to 2 1D vectors.
Where:

f(x,y) = f(x)*f(y)

Then F(u,v) = F(u)*F(v)

Using the following code:

```
% Separabilty of signal 
H = [-1,2,-1;-2,4,-2;-1,2,-1];
b3 = fft2(H)
Hx = [-1,2,-1];
Hy = [1,2,1]';
c2 = fft(Hy)*fft(Hx')'
if norm(vecnorm(b3-c2)) < 1e-5
    "same"
else
    "different"
end
```

But, though the numbers are correct, their ordering inside the matrix is shifted. I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here

```
c2 = fft(Hy)*fft(Hx')'
```

Why do you apply the double transposition `fft(Hx')'`?

Since

```
H = Hy*Hx
```

then

```
c2 = fft(Hy)*fft(Hx)
```

Note that in matlab the operation `'` performs the complex conjugate transpose, that is the reason why `fft(Hx)` is not equal to `fft(Hx')'`, since the second transposition changes the sign of the imaginary part.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The 1st transpose is because the fft function only accepts a vector not a row as input. The 2nd is to match the size of the matrices to get a matrix product. I didn't realize that the ' operator also takes the conjugate of the matrix... Is there an operator that only takes transpose?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html